# Adding line at particular location in chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a configuration file `/etc/csync/csync2.cfg` with a format as this,

```
group ha_group
{
        key /etc/csync2/key_hagroup;
        host host1;
        host host2;
        include /etc/booth;
        include /etc/corosync/corosync.conf;
        include /etc/corosync/authkey;
}
```

I want to figure out if an entry exists(e.g. `include /var/tsm/tsm/tsm.conf;`). If it does, do nothing and if not, add it.

I've checked poise-file and line cookbooks in the chef supermarket. Problem with the actions provided in those cookbooks is if the entry is not present, they add it to the end of the file.

My usecase requires it to be added within the braces `{}` and not the end of the file.
I cannot template the file because the contents of `/etc/csync/csync2.cfg` may vary from node to node.

Another alternative was checking if the csync2 command line has any option to add new entries https://github.com/LINBIT/csync2/blob/master/doc/csync2.adoc
to avoid processsing in recipe

Answer (score 1):

you might find [poise-file](https://github.com/poise/poise-file), [line](https://github.com/sous-chefs/line) cookbooks handy or use [FileEdit](https://rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Util/FileEdit) directly

```
file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/hosts")
file.insert_line_if_no_match("/www.example.com/", "www.example.com")
file.write_file
```

Comment: That would insert the line at the end of the file though isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround it with [FileEdit](https://rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Util/FileEdit), by additionally deleting the `}` line and inserting it at the end.

```
file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/hosts")
file.insert_line_if_no_match("/www.example.com/", "www.example.com")
file.search_file_delete_line('}')
file.insert_line_if_no_match('}') 
file.write_file
```

Comment: isn't FileEdit deprecated?

Comment: The issue is still open https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/7043 . So they probably just considering to deprecate it, but haven't discovered any alternative for now.